# Cant make my jquery animate back with click

Tags: jquery, html, click, jquery-animate

Sorry for posting this if this is already answered. But i´ve searched and couldnt understand what to do.

I have a div with a plus sign image and a div below it with some information.
When I click the plus sign both the div animates up, but when I click the plus sign again nothing happens.

I would like it to work like this - Clicking the plussign both div animates up, clicking the plussign OR leaving the bigdiv animates it back.

This is what i got so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.plussign').click(function(event) {
        $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '400px'}, 200);
        $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '400px'}, 200);
    }).click(function(event) {
        $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '80px'}, 200);
        $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '80px'}, 200);
    });;
});
```

Comment: use `.toggle(function A, function B)` if you want to do two things on a button click alternatively. `A` will be run on first and odd clicks, `B` will be run on second and even clicks... Registering click() twice like you did will fire both functions at the same time.

Comment: umm like this?:

jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.plussign').toggle(function a(event) {
        $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '400px'}, 200);
        $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '400px'}, 200);
    }).toggle(function b(event) {
        $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '80px'}, 200);
        $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '80px'}, 200);
    });;
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.plussign').toggle(function(event) {
        $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '400px'}, 200);
        $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '400px'}, 200);
    }, function(event) {
        $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '80px'}, 200);
        $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '80px'}, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I got it working with this script! 
Is there a way to modify this so that if i also click on the bigdiv it animates back and also add if I mouseleave the bigdiv it animates back? Incase people dont understand to click

Comment: In that case you should store your state in some variable, and according to it display or hide elements in appropriate handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use toggle.
Try the below script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.plussign').toggle(
        function() {
            $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '400px'}, 200);
            $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '400px'}, 200);
        }, function() {
            $('#bigdiv').animate({height : '80px'}, 200);
            $('.plussign').animate({bottom : '80px'}, 200);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: THanks for the fast reply! However I ended up using pckills method, it seemed to be working best for me and what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//  BTW, if you're using newer jQuery and no other library that namespaces the $ symbol, 
//  you can replace that long document.ready line with the following:
//  $(function() {
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    //  call just one click function
    $('.plussign').click(function(e) {
        //  using toggle function will allow you to operate between the two clicks
        $(this).toggle(function(e) {    //  click odd
            //  If both elements are recieving the same action, then call them in the same line, 
            //  simply seperate with a comma
            $('#bigdiv, .plussign').stop().animate({height : '400px'}, 200);
            //  the .stop() function will stop any previous animation and continue with the new, 
            //  this is usefull for FAST CLICKING
        },
        function(e) {   //  click even
            $('#bigdiv, .plussign').stop().animate({height : '80px'}, 200);
        });
    });
})
```

> **HOWEVER**

I would suggest using a base class and a toggle class and using jQuery's .toggleClass feature as it is far less coding and easier to control in that you can simply adjust css.
For example:

> CSS

```
.open { 
    height: 400px;
}
.closed { 
    height: 80px;
}
```

> SCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    //  if you dont add the closed class to the html element itself on the HTML, 
    //  you can add it here before setting your click event
    $('#bigdiv, .plussign').addClass("closed");
    //  then set your click event with the toggleClass function
    $('.plussign').click(function(e) {
        $('#bigdiv, .plussign').toggleClass("open closed");
        // if you add jQueryUI to the mix you can control the speed in time as follows
        // $('#bigdiv, .plussign').toggleClass("open closed", 10000);
    });
})
```

Comment: A weird bug happen on this one =/ I used pckill example and it worked well for me. Thanks for such a fast and helpful reply!